# Standard Tiles displaying particular number of records present in database table

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to create a page with standard tiles inside a tile container displaying the number of records (that are approved/ rejected/ pending) present in table made in view called by that tile not the entries of complete table.

The following code displays the records present in whole table.

Here's the code:

*tiletest.view.js*

```
var oDataModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("https://.../tiletest/tile.xsodata", true);

var items;
oDataModel.read("/Expense", null, null, false, function success(oData) {
        items = oData.results.length;
    },
    function failure() {});
var page1 = new sap.m.Page("page1", {
        showHeader: false
    }),
    content: [
        new sap.m.TileContainer({
            tiles: [
                new sap.m.StandardTile("tile", {
                    title: "Request",
                    info: "Create Request",
                    infoState: "Success",
                    press: function() {
                        oController.ab();
                    }
                }),
                new sap.m.StandardTile("tile1", {
                    number: items,
                    title: "Approved",
                    info: "Approved Requests",
                    infoState: "Success",
                    press: function() {
                        oController.appr();
                    }
                }),
                new sap.m.StandardTile("tile2", {
                    number: items,
                    title: "Rejected",
                    info: "Rejected Request",
                    infoState: "Warning",
                    press: function() {
                        oController.appr1();
                    }
                })
            ]
        })
    ]
});

return page1;
}
```

*tiletest.controller.js*

```
sap.ui.controller("test1.tiletest", {
    ab: function() {
        var app = sap.ui.getCore().byId("AppID");
        app.to("list_id2");
    },

    ab2: function() {
        var app = sap.ui.getCore().byId("AppID");
        app.to("list_id6");
    },

    appr: function() {
        var app = sap.ui.getCore().byId("AppID");
        app.to("list_id4");
    }
});
```

*tile.xsodata*

```
service{
"DATABASE_NAME"."TABLE_NAME" as "Expense";
 }
```

Comment: Looks nice. Is there a problem?

Comment: problem is how to display the Approved or Rejected requests in Standard Tile's  "number" property. I want to select the records which have approved and display its number on its Approved tile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code given below will fetch the number of requests approved or rejected and display in Tile number.

**tiletest.view.js**

```
    createContent : function(oController) {
  var oDataModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("https://accountname/packagename/tile.xsodata", true);


var appritems,rejectitems;


oDataModel.read("/Expense/?$filter=STATUS eq 'Approved'", null, null, false,function success(oData){ appritems=oData.results.length;}, function failure(){});
oDataModel.read("/Expense/?$filter=STATUS eq 'Rejected'", null, null, false,function success(oData){ rejectitems=oData.results.length;}, function failure(){});
 var items;
var page1 = new sap.m.Page("page1", {
    content :[
 new sap.m.TileContainer({
    tiles : [ 
 new sap.m.StandardTile("tile1",{
        number: appritems,
        title : "Approved",
        info:  "Approved Requests",
        infoState : "Success",
        press : function() {
          oController.appr();
        }
    }),
    new sap.m.StandardTile("tile2",{
        number: rejectitems,
        title : "Rejected",
         info:  "Rejected Request",
         infoState : "Warning",
        press : function() {
            oController.appr1();
        }
    })

     ]

})
            ]
});
return page1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To display the number of approved or rejected requests, you'd have to run 2 ODataModel.read statements that fetch a $count based on the right filter. E.g.:

```
// These filters are the filters that should be applied to your tile count
var _mFilters = {
    approved: [new sap.ui.model.Filter("Approved", "EQ", true)],
    rejected: [new sap.ui.model.Filter("Rejected", "EQ", true)]
};

// These are the counts that should be displayed on your filter buttons.
// Bind them from your view
var oViewModel = new JSONModel({
    approved: 0,
    rejected: 0
});
this.getView().setModel(oViewModel, "view");

// This will run the 2 read statement. One with each of the filters in 
// effect. The result will go into the oViewModel values declared above.
jQuery.each(_mFilters, function (sFilterKey, oFilter) {
    oModel.read("/Expense/$count", {
        filters: oFilter,
        success: function (oData) {
            var sPath = "/" + sFilterKey;
            oViewModel.setProperty(sPath, oData);
        }
    });
});
```

If you then bind the count properties of the Tile controls, e.g.: {view>matMaster}. Every tile should display it's respective count.